# Google Sheets - Query - Concatenate text to returned data

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I would like to add an Hyperlink to the output data. Something like:

```
HYPERLINK("https://www.google.ca/search?q="&QUERY_RESULT, QUERY_RESULT)
```

So I would have a column of one or more results that would be an Hyperlink.

If it can help, my query look like that:

```
=QUERY(A:K; "select B where I contains 'Done' ORDER BY B ASC LABEL B 'Results'"; 4)
```

I think I could use a CONCAT function, but I am not sure how I would write this down in a GSheets Query. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just use a helper column. Query output in B, hyperlink column in A...

Comment: I can give an Excel answer (since it's tagged [tag:excel] anyway!) ... your first example  should work fine. You can concatenate like `="abc" & "def"` or `=CONCAT("abc","def")`.

Comment: When you have "no idea" how to use a function, I'd suggested checking the documentation for syntax and examples.  In this case: [**CONCAT**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093592)

Answer (score 1):

QUERY produces a array. You need to explicitly mention that your formula is a ARRAYFORMULA:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(HYPERLINK("https://www.google.ca/search?q="&QUERY_RESULT, QUERY_RESULT))
```